# Javascript Issue on Dynamic Preloading

Tags: php, javascript, preload

So I'm using a central "engine" to run content for an HTML5 game. I can drop it into any framework I want and it handles all the drawing and setting up the canvas', etc. In order to make it as user-friendly as possible, I'm using a PHP script to search out all game-specific files and add them in. PHP passes a JSON array of all the files and they're loaded one by one into the game via Javascript.

Sounds great, and has worked great for several projects now, but suddenly I'm finding that some of the files need to be loaded in an order-dependent way. I could explicitly list them and load them (like the engine core files...) but that defeats the purpose of loading them dynamically (user friendly).

Is there any sort of way to define which ones get loaded first? I've seen a jQuery extension that I want to say was called RequireJS, but I'll be honest that its documentation was a bit over my head. I tried implementing it but just ran into error after error.

Any suggestions or has anyone tried to do something similar?

Comment: Would merging files server-side, caching them and sending to the user as one big js file be acceptable?

Comment: That's not a bad idea, actually. But how would each potential user define a load order to the PHP script?

Comment: Instead of passing a JSON array of scripts, you can make somthing like a md5 hash of a string that contains names of the files. If such files doesn't exists, you load the content of all js files, put them in one file and save it with the name {md5hash}.js, then send the md5hash to the user to put this result script into the dom and load it. Prestashop does this, for example, if you know anywhing about that.